# Is expiari an alternate form of the infinitive expiare?

Tags: infinitive

I take the following sentence from Fabules Faciles:

> ...hōc enim ūnō modō tantum scelus expiārī potuit

as "...only in this way could he atone for such a great crime." literally, "indeed in this one way for such an extent of crime to atone was he able". So, expiari seems to be an infinitive ("to atone"). However, I thought that the infinitive of expior was expiare, not expiari. Is it a subjunctive infinitive or something? This form, *expiari*, is not even listed in the grammar I use (https://www.online-latin-dictionary.com/).

Comment: It shows up for me, if I search on that site (online-latin-dictionary.com).

Comment: Happy to hear Fab. Fac. Fabulae Faciles still going strong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're correct that this is an infinitive! It's just the *passive* infinitive, rather than the active, so I would read *scelus* as the subject rather than the person atoning.

Rearranging the words into an English order rather than a Latin one, we get:

> …enim hōc scelus potuit **expiārī** ūnō modō
> *…for this crime was able **to be atoned for** in only one way*

The passive infinitives for the four conjugations are *am-ārī*, *hab-ērī*, *dīc-ī*, and *aud-īrī*. The third conjugation is the only weird one to learn; the others just replace the final *-e* of the active infinitive with *-ī*.